# How to print out the value of a SQLHSTMT variable in DB2 SQL?

Tags: sql, c, db2

Having the code like the sample below:

```
SQLHANDLE listings_hstmt;
SQLRETURN InsertListing( struct listing *l, int *errorCode )
{
    ...
    sqlrc = SQLBindParameter( listings_hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &update_id, 0, NULL );
    CHECK_STMT_ERR( listings_hstmt, sqlrc );

    sqlrc = SQLBindParameter( listings_hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_LONG, SQL_INTEGER, 0, 0, &exchange_id, 0, NULL );
    CHECK_STMT_ERR( listings_hstmt, sqlrc );

    len = 1;
    sqlrc = SQLBindParameter( listings_hstmt, 3, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_CHAR, 1, 0, (SQLCHAR*)&(l->action), 1, &len );
    CHECK_STMT_ERR( listings_hstmt, sqlrc );
    ...
    sqlrc = SQLExecute( listings_hstmt ) ;
    ...
}
```

Running the program, I got this error:

```
[IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQLSTATE 01517: A character that could not be converted was replaced with a substitute character.
```

I wanted to print out the sql statement to see the detail, so added something like this:

```
printf("   The statement is %s\n", listings_hstmt);
```

Yet, with this debug `printf` added, all I can get is a segmentation fault.

So, how could I get to know what the final sql statement is before it is executed?

P.S.: The OS is CentOS Linux, while we are using DB2 as the backend database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over your client application, presumably you could print out the value of all of the bound variables prior to calling `SQLExecute()`.

Or, perhaps better, print out the values of the bound variables only if the SQLExecute call fails.

Short of doing that, you would have to turn on tracing at the client level or use some event monitors at the server level.  Both of these options will generate a LOT of data, which probably won't be too useful for this kind of debugging work.

Comment: Thank you, Ian. So there is no direct way to print out the detailed, value populated sql statement run in `SQLExecute()`? I am trying to print out the values before they go into `SQLExecute()`, but that's really tedious and not as straightforward as if the final sql statement could be printed.  :-(

Comment: The SQL statement as the database sees it is something like `SELECT C1, C2 from T1 where C3 = ? and C4 = ?` – the `?` are parameters.  When your program calls `SQLPrepare()`, the statement is sent to the database and is compiled.  When you bind variables in your application to the parameters in the SQL statement, only the values are passed to the database engine each time your application calls `SQLExecute()`.  The database engine already has the (compiled) SQL statement, and it just fills in the values received from the `SQLExecute()` call.